# Mongoid multi threading

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Lets say I'm creating a new thread inside my web app and using Mongoid to update a model, how will Mongoid manage the connection to the db? Is this written anywhere in docs?

Comment: What do you mean by how will Mongoid manage the connections?

Comment: Will it use same connection? open a new connection per thread? when will it close the connection? do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Well mongoid uses a pool of connection. even in your application, it can open multiple connections if necessary. It doesnt matter if you do something in different thread. Under the hood mongoid uses mongodb connection mechanism. On normal condition it immediately closes the connection and kills the thread after task is complete. You should not worry about it.

Comment: Where did you found this info?

Comment: Few time back i was working on a project with multiple connections and mongodb mirroring using mongoid. I ran into a problem with connection pools managed by mongodb. That time i did an extensive research about mongodb and how it works with the connections.

Comment: So, wanna post a formal answer? and maybe we'll add it to mongoid docs?

Comment: I am totally not good at writing formal answers especially for docs.

Comment: review https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-installation/#configuration